# имеется код показа уведомлений через n время, нужно чтобы время не сбрасывалось при обновлении страницы а хранилось в сессии

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
`var time = setTimeout(noti, 9000);
function noti() {
  document.getElementById('notifications').style.display = "flex";
  time = setTimeout(noti,9000);
}
function clock(){
/*код на кнопку "закрывает уведомление" - сбрасывает таймер и запускает время снова*/
    clearInterval(time);
    setTimeout(noti,9000);
}`
```

Comment: Сохраняйте и проверяйте время по timestamp

Comment: можно пожалуйста по подробнее, я прогуглил , но решения так и не нашел, там другой код , а мне нужно провести все это с данным кодом, уведомление появляется через 15 минут, но при обновлении счетчик сбрасывается, и я не знаю как сохранить счетчик времени

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

При когда пользователь закрывает уведомление, мы сохраняем в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) и я бы ещё сохранял через какое время показать повторно.
Выглядело бы это следующим образом:

```
//                         Разделитель, чтоб попроще ↴
localStorage.setItem('notifyTime', new Date().now()+':'+9000);
```

Далее, когда пользователь обновляет страницу, мы в начале получаем данные которые сохраняли делим через [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), складываем их, и сверяем, если полученное число больше текущего **timestamp** - то можно показывать уведомление, ибо время прошло.
Если меньше, то мы вычитаем сохранённый **timestamp** от текущего и получим время сколько осталось до конца, с этим временем запускаем таймер, по истечению которого показываем уведомление снова.

```
let old = localStorage.getItem('notifyTime').split(':'),
    cur = new Date().now();

old = Number(old[0]) + Number(old[1]);

if(old > cur) {
  // Показываем уведомление
} else {
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Показываем уведомление
  }, cur-old);
}
```

После первого запуска советую запустить таймер, чтобы пользователю показало уведомление, если вдруг пользователь не надумает обновлять страницу.